# Understanding reference counting and metaclasses

Tags: python, reference, python-2.x

I'm trying to do some things with metaclasses and I don't understand the result of this my python code.

```
import sys

class Meta(type):
    a = None
    b = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        name = args[0]
        if getattr(cls, name) is None:
            setattr(cls, name, super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs))
        return getattr(cls, name)


class A:
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self, name, in_a = None):
        self.a = None
        if in_a:
            self.a = in_a


a = A("a")

print sys.getrefcount(a) - 2  # 1

b = A("b", a)

print sys.getrefcount(a) - 2  # 2

b = None

print sys.getrefcount(a) - 2  # 2?
```

I have two reference on `a`, one of them is an attribute of `b`.

When I remove the reference `b` (or set to `None`), the count of refences on `a` is still 2.

Now, when I don't use metaclasses, it works well :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, in_a = None):
        self.a = None
        if in_a is not None:
            self.a = in_a


a = A()

print sys.getrefcount(a) - 1  # 1

b = A(a)

print sys.getrefcount(a) - 1  # 2

b = None

print sys.getrefcount(a) - 1  # 1
```

Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Why do you subtract `2` with the metaclass, but only `1` without it?

Comment: because i store one additional reference in class : setattr(cls, name, super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs))

Comment: That reference keeps the original `b` alive, and it still has a reference to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

With your code, `b` is also stored as `A.b`, so just setting the global `b` to `None` doesn't trigger collection of this instance - because there's still a ref to it - so the refcount stay constants. IOW, you forgot to check the refcount on `b` ;-)

Just add `A.b = None` and you will see the refcount go down.

Note that it has nothing to do with metaclasses (not sure what you're trying to do here actually but there's probably a much simpler/obvious solution).